# On the equation $a^4+b^4+c^4=2d^4$ in coprime positive integers $a\lt b\lt c$ such that $a+b\ne c$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

**Background:** The equation

$$a^4+b^4+c^4=2d^4$$

has infinitely many positive integral solutions if we take $c=a+b$ and $a^2+ab+b^2=d^2$ further assuming that $GCD(a,b,c)=1$.

**Main problem:** Find some positive integral solutions to the equation

$$a^4+b^4+c^4=2d^4$$

with $a\lt b\lt c\ne a+b$ and $GCD(a,b,c)=1$.

Comment: $a = 4014369822293252845298556668977$  
                $b = 8028813922964684804294250901215$  
                $c = 8331871536210073175631303374584$  
                $d = 8243128117136361914922521992201$

Comment: Jovan, you need to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: @user25406 I'm satisfied with the Tomita's answer.

Comment: There are no solutions for $c\le300$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $A=\frac{a}{d}, B=\frac{b}{d}, C=\frac{c}{d},$ then we get

$$A^4+B^4+C^4=2\tag{1}$$

Let $A=x+y, B=x-y, z=C^2$ then

$$2x^4+12y^2x^2+2y^4+z^2 = 2\tag{2}$$

Hence

$$y^2 = -3x^2 \pm \frac{\sqrt{32x^4+4-2z^2}}{2}\tag{3}$$

So we find the rational solutions of $(4)$.

$$v^2=32x^4+4-2z^2\tag{4}$$

$(4)$ can be parameterized to $(5)$ using $(z,v)=(4x^2,2)$ with $w=(k^2+2)C$.

$$w^2 = 4(k^2+2)(-2+k^2)x^2-4(k^2+2)k\tag{5}$$

Thus we must find the rational solutions of simultaneous equations $(3),(5)$.

First we get a parametric solution of $(5)$ using giving some rational number $k$.

Take $k=\frac{-9}{13}$. Then we get:

$$x = \frac{3}{142}\frac{28561m^2-430732-7081100m}{28561m^2+430732}$$
$$w = \frac{-1257}{11999}\frac{-10768300+173732m+714025m^2}{28561m^2+430732}$$
$$C = \frac{-3}{71}\frac{-10768300+173732m+714025m^2}{28561m^2+430732}$$

Hence $(3)$ becomes

$$y^2 = \frac{10083247442281m^4-41255619857608m^2+2788930240200m^3+2293337020040464-42060204482400m}{20164(28561m^2+430732)^2}$$

Hence we must find the rational solutions $(m,V)$ of $(6)$
$$V^2 = 10083247442281m^4+2788930240200m^3-41255619857608m^2-42060204482400m+2293337020040464\tag{6}$$

Quartic equation $(6)$ is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve using a known solution $(m,V)=(360/169,-47445892)$ as follows.
$$Y^2 = X^3 -X^2 -1097465452X+ 3288951361780\tag{7}$$

Though I couldn't find the generator of elliptic curve , I got one solution
$P(X,Y)=(\cfrac{-97636631990}{5536609}, \cfrac{53963430434179560}{13027640977})$.

Since $(7)$ has rank $1$, we get infinitely many solutions of $(7)$ using group law as follows.

For instance, we get a solution of $(6)$,
$2Q(m,V)=(\cfrac{-762617488871059540}{36474714629699307},\cfrac{-63980049963485293932709632365019549028}{46581170383319934672021751209})$

We get $(x,y)=(\cfrac{4317501713916820330332746705607}{16486256234272723829845043984402},\cfrac{12346241358503326020929860043561}{16486256234272723829845043984402})$

Finally, we get

$a = 4014369822293252845298556668977$
$b = 8028813922964684804294250901215$
$c = 8331871536210073175631303374584$
$d = 8243128117136361914922521992201$

Comment: Elegant, but why do you suppose this solution is so far from minimal? See the other answer.

Comment: I tried to make it understandable without much prerequisite knowledge.

Comment: If everyone were a professional mathematician, maybe $10$ lines answer might be enough.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Maybe has to do with the fact it was not brute-force but a rational point on an elliptic curve. Quite similar to this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4632152/4781) about _co-prime_ solutions to $a^4+b^4+c^4 = 9d^2$ where an elliptic curve yields $$2682440^4+15365639^4+18796760^4 = 9\times141668657747643^2$$ but the smallest by brute force is only $$155^4+260^4+296^4 = 9\times37747^2.$$

Comment: We can actually ask the same question about my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3427704/simple-continued-fraction-of-sqrtd-with-period-of-shortest-length-3). By using a specific form I prove that square roots of integers can give any continued fraction repeat length, but by going for a universally valid structure I sacrifice minimality unless the repeat length happens to be 1 or 3. Might this be a similar trade-off?

Comment: If we take the point $Q(m)=\frac{360}{169}$ then we get a small solution $(a,b,c,d)=( 32, 1065, 2321, 1973).$
The large solution corresponds to the point $2Q(m)=\cfrac{-762617488871059540}{36474714629699307}.$

Comment: Problem: Are almost all integral points to $a^4+b^4+c^4=2d^4$, $0\lt a\lt b\lt c$, of the form $(a,b,a+b,\sqrt{a^2+ab+b^2})$ for some positive integers $a,b$?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440909/on-the-equation-a4b4c4-2d4-in-natural-numbers-with-abcd?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: I could assume $\gcd(a,b)=1$ in my second previous comment.

Comment: @Tomita What a perfect answer!

Answer (score 20):

$(a, b, c, d) = (32, 1065, 2321, 1973), (2156, 5605, 8381, 7383)$

Comment: did you use an algorithm or brute force?

Comment: @user25406 brute force